# I am Getting The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>'. Try defining the operator '[]' error

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey there I am new to flutter and currently encountering an error i.e when i return username i get   the error that method is not defined.The error inside builder in futurebuilder when i return textwidget with username. I Added null safety check but still didnt amount to nothing as it gives me an error .I wonder why its hapening .

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class messagebubble extends StatelessWidget {
  // const messagebubble({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  messagebubble(this.message, this.isMe, this.userID, {required this.key});
  final String message;
  final bool isMe;
  final Key key;
  final String userID;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isMe ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                bottomLeft: !isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(12),
                bottomRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(12),
              ),
            ),
            width: 150,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
            child: Column(children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(userID)
                      .get(),
                  builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Text('Loading ...');
                    }
                    return Text(
                    snapshot.data!['username'],
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    );
                  }),
               Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color:
                        isMe ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.purple),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use .snapshot() instead of .get() in future

```
future : FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(userID)
                      .snapshots()
may it is works
```

Comment: unfortunately doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution that might work for you**

```
 builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshots){
     if (snapshots.hasData) {
     return Center(child: Text("hasData"),);

     }
    if (snapshots.hasError) {
     return Center(child: Text("hasError"),);

      
    }

      return Center(child: Text("wait....."),);
```

Add to  builder (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshots)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).